# Prove that the solution to this differential equation $\sec x \frac{dy}{dx} = e^{y+ \sin x}$ is $y= - \ln ( C - e^{\sin x}) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the solution to this differential equation $\sec x \frac{dy}{dx} = e^{y+ \sin x}$ is $y= - \ln ( C - e^{\sin x}) $

Separating the expressions involving $x$ and $y$,

$\int e^{-y}dy = \int \cos x (e^{\sin x}) dx$

$- e^{-y} = e^{\sin x} + C_1 $

Expressing it in logarithm form:

$ - \ln e^{-y} = \ln e^{\sin x} + \ln C_1 $

$- (-y) = \ln e^{\sin x} + \ln C_1 $

I can't seem to prove the general solution of the differential equation

Comment: $\ln(A+B)$ is in general not equal to $\ln(A)+\ln(B)$, in fact there is no useful simplification. There are useful transformations to equally complex expressions.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing looks okay, except your use of logarithm properties that don't work.

You could try verifying what you are given is a solution

First exponentiate both sides of your original expression for $y$ to get $e^y=\dfrac{1}{C-e^{\sin x}}$

Next take the derivative of your expression for $y$ (Don't forget the chain rule):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\cos xe^{\sin x}}{C-e^{\sin x}}$

I'll leave manipulating this into the original differential equation up to you at this point.

If you have a theorem that tells you the size of a fundamental set of solutions you may be finished just by verifying what you have is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$- e^{-y} = e^{\sin x} + C_1$$
This line is not correct:
$$−\ln e^{−y}=\ln e^{\sin x}+\ln C_1$$

Note that:
$$\ln a +\ln b=\ln ab$$
But: $$\ln(a+b) \ne \ln a +\ln b$$